# Adding colours at the header and footer and reducing the box size of the header

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox

I am new to the Latex. I have tried my hand on this in developing a document with the header and footer.
I almost succeeded with the google resources plus this forum. But still I need to fix two issues, please help me with that.

- To add a maroon color in the header and footer box.
- To reduce the box size of the header

Below is the code, please guide me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%% a garbage package you don't need except to create examples.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newlength{\fminilength}%
\setlength{\fminilength}{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\fminilength}%
      \ttfamily\upshape box upto end of this text \hfill 
    \end{minipage}%
  }}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4 pt}  

\lfoot{\noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\fminilength}%
      \ttfamily\upshape Wireless networking \hfill \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
    \end{minipage}%
  }}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}



\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

below is the image to describe the expecting output;

![image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. Your question is tagged with `tcolorbox` but that package is not used at all?

Comment: I am not sure but I think "tcolorbox" package is used to color the header and footer box. In that way, was looking for someone to guide me in using that package and solve the issue posted.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a screen shot how your document (or a page of it) should look like? And at a quick look on your code I cannot recognize where `tcolorbox` is used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, I have added the picture on how document should like. And maybe I have misguided you, I did not add 'tcolorbox' package and was looking for help whether the package could solve issues.

Comment: Maroon is a dark color, at least according to Wikipedia (RGB 128,0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this provides the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%% a garbage package you don't need except to create examples.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\definecolor{maroon}{RGB}{128,0,0}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newlength{\fminilength}%
\setlength{\fminilength}{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\noindent%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=maroon,width=0.3\textwidth,outer arc=0mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,boxrule=0mm]
Header
%\ttfamily\upshape box upto end of this text \hfill
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4 pt}  

\lfoot{\noindent%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=maroon,width=\textwidth,outer arc=0mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm, boxrule=0mm]
Footer\hfill \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
%%      \ttfamily\upshape Wireless networking \hfill \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

I removed the boxrules about the `tcolorbox` environments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This was exact document what I  was looking for, but I could not able to load tcolorbox.sty. There was an error stating tcolorbox.sty is not found.

Comment: Normaly it is included on `TeXlive`. See the rich documentation of `tcolorbox`. It is full of examples etc, in order to do fine tuning of your boxes.

Comment: I am uing Miktex andd Texmaker, would that be a problem??

Comment: @user50327: I use neither of them, but it should be not too difficult to install the package from CTAN and place it at some place where TeXMaker etc. finds it. See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox.zip

Comment: It works completely fine. There was some kind of black border around the footer and header box. Any means to remove that, please help on that. thank you!!

Comment: @user50327: The frame around the boxes can be removed by setting the `boxrule=0mm` option to `tcolorbox` environment, see my updated 'solution'